# SQL Query Convert columns to rows

Tags: sql, sum, pivot, unpivot

```
select sum(cases) as [Total cases], sum(deaths) as [Total deaths] 
FROM [myschema].[metrics]
```

[image: Query output]

Can we get by pivot/unpivot function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use UNPIVOT to get the desired result also:

```
   SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            SUM(cases)      AS total_cases,
            SUM(deaths)     AS total_deaths
        FROM
            myschema.metrics
    ) UNPIVOT ( value
        FOR category
    IN ( total_cases,
         total_deaths ) );
```

The output of the above will be:

```
Category                Value
Total_cases             1234
Total_deaths            123
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `union all`:

```
select 'total cases' info, sum(cases) cnt from metrics
union all select 'total deaths', sum(deaths) from metrics
```

Or, if your database supports lateral joins:

```
select x.info, sum(x.cnt) cnt
from metrics m
cross join lateral (values ('total cases', m.cases), ('total deaths', m.deaths)) as x(info, cnt)
group by x.info
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest generic way in is `union all`:

```
select 'Total Cases'  as which, sum(cases) 
from [myschema].[metrics]
union all
select 'Total Deaths' as which, sum(deaths)
from [myschema].[metrics];
```

The square braces look like SQL Server.  I would recommend a lateral join in that case:

```
select v.*
from (select sum(cases) as TotalCases, sum(deaths) as TotalDeaths 
      from [myschema].[metrics]
     ) m cross apply
     (values ('TotalCases', TotalCases), ('TotalDeaths', TotalDeaths)
     ) v(which, cnt);
```

This reads the table only once.  And if the table is really a more complicated query (say a view or CTE), the performance gain can be substantial.